# The best way of update records in MySQL from XML feed

Tags: mysql, xml, database

I am thinking about the best way, how to update my records in table (MySQL) from XML feed. I have database and this database contains the daily offers from several sales portals.
So now - about midnight I am deleting all records from my table (because I think is better delete everything from table than comparing currently data with inserted) and with using script (run of CRON) I am downloading new offers from portal (by their XML feeds). This way have one disadvantage -- the time interval among deleting old and inserting new records is ca 5 minutes -- and through this 5 minutes is table empty.

And I would like to ask you, if you could help me with some better way, how updating records in my table using better way...

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: How much do the daily offers change from day to day? Wouldn't it be better to do inserts/updates/(soft) deletes instead of drop-and-replace?

Comment: The change is occurring once of the day (at midnight). The problem is, that the count of the feeds is more than 100 and every XML feed have thousands records (max. 20.000 I guess). So I think the comparison of records would be more demanding

Comment: But out of these 20,000, how many are different from the 20,000 that came yesterday? From my experience, deletes are the most demanding for the database resources.

Comment: What about using REPLACE INTO?

Comment: I guess most of the items are the same, but... isn't most demanding comparison every item from feed with item in database? (ok, I will try to finding time-difference). 
I wonder about one problem - the feeds, which will be importing to database, will be among 100 and 1000 -- so what would be the best way of process so many feeds? Turn off time limit for processing script on server or processing after 20 feeds? And the language? I hesitate among PHP and RoR (rather RoR)

Comment: REPLACE INTO? I must googling, I never used it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would import the new xml feeds into a temporary table, keeping the old table active; and then when all imports are successful, you can simply drop the original table and rename the new to be the original.  This should result in less downtime, but more importantly it will give you the ability to abort the switch in the event the new import of XML fails on a given night.

hope that helps.

Comment: Baily: What about indexes and foreign key constraints? How they would work during dropping the original tables and renaming the new ones?

Comment: Good question, Olaf.  My response above is just what I think is the most efficient and fail-safe way to do what he's doing.  He's simply deleting the entire table's contents and then recreating it; so if he has indexes or other constraints that he cares about, then he can choose when to set them: before or after the drop/rename.  Inserts and table drops are much faster than either record deletes or record updates, and indexes and constraints may be added at any time.